# Bug in Suggested Edits -- shows 4 suggested edits but none when i click on the link

Tags: bug

I just updated some wiki tags.. I see 4 suggested edits pending in my screen.. When i click on the link i see "There are no items for you to review."

I believe it's a bug. Since, Edits are pending approval by other members who has privilege and i cannot approve which were edited by me.

Is it a bug or designed like that ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is by design: The number of suggested edits is cached, and its value is valid for every user who has the privilege of reviewing the suggested edit. Since that value is shown on every page of the site you visit, it makes sense to cache it to avoid running expensive queries for every user with that privilege.